# Better way to delete values from Multiple lists based on Index using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Can we do it better than the below logic , provided I would like to know if we can use list comprehension .

```
FruitsList = ["apples","mangoes","banana","grapes","peaches","kiwi"]
numbersList = [1,2,None,5,None,100]

for num in numbersList:
    if num == None:
        indexnum = numbersList.index(None)
        print indexnum
        del numbersList[indexnum]
        del FruitsList [indexnum]

print FruitsList #['apples', 'mangoes', 'grapes', 'peaches']
print numbersList #[1, 2, 5, 4]
```

Comment: How big are the lists? Moving items is going to be expensive for bigger lists, better create new lists and assign them to the same variables.

Comment: Should you have 'kiwi' and not 'peaches' in the resulting FruitsList?  It looks like you want to drop the fruits in positions that correspond to None in NumbersList, but the last fruit confuses me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
s = [(a, b) for (a,b) in zip(FruitsList, numbersList) if b is not None]
FruitsList = [x[0] for x in s]
numbersList = [x[1] for x in s]
```

but this gives

```
['apples', 'mangoes', 'grapes', 'kiwi']
```

for the fruits as I said in my comment.  If this isn't right, let me know and I'll see of I can amend this answer (or delete it.)

EDIT:  Notice that I had to change s from a generator comprehension, with outer parentheses, to a list comprehension with outer square brackets.  The generator comprehension builds a generator, which saves on memory, and may be faster, but you can only iterate though it once, so after building the FruitsList, the generator is empty, and when we try to iterate through it again to build the numbersList, it's empty.

Comment: @ saulspatz - first thing I apologize it was my mistake, the output you gave is correct for FruitsList
. Second point - the numbersList is empty list when I print it.

Comment: I'm an idiot!  I had it working, then I made a little change to make it "more efficient"  and broke it.  You need to use a list comprehension, not a generator, because when you iterate the generator once, you've exhausted it.  A list comprehension. on the other hand, builds a list.  I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps one could try something like this

```
[FruitsList[i] for i in range(0, min(len(FruitsList), len(numbersList))) if not numbersList[i] is None]
```